# Spring @asynch thread concurrency shared resources

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, threadpool

In my Service I need to have *n* different threads that run stuff on *n* different directories (*n* goes from 1 to 8).

I need to execute *k* different task(*k* goes from 1 to 10000), each task is bound to a single directory, I need to execute the *k1* task on the *n1* directory only when there are no active threads on *n1* .

I'm new to Spring and I'd like to use @async annotation, and I haven't understand how to set pool in this case.

```
for(int task = 1; task<=1000;task++){
   executeAsynchMethod( directoryNumber);
}
```

executeAsynchMethod should stay idle until there are no other task on the same directory.

UPDATE:
example:
   An executeAsynchMethod starts on every available thread:
          thread1 -> works on directory 1
          thread2 -> works on directory 2
                    ...
          threadn -> works on directory n
Whenever a thread finish its work it "frees" its directory and I want that a task runs on this directory.
           thread7 -> directory7 is free
           thread7(or another free thread) -> start a new task on directory7

Comment: Can you split tasks beforehand by the directory they have to run on and then run them sequentially?

Comment: No because tasks can have really different execution times (from 10 seconds to 10 minutes) and I want to have all the possible threads active during the whole execution. 

I don't even know which are the longer tasks :D

Comment: But if there are x1 tasks on n1 directory, the execution time will take at least x1*duration regardless of what you do. However, if some other tasks will take less time, `ThreadPool` will make sure the next task will get executed by the freed up task.

Comment: My fault it was ambiguous;the x-th task isn't bound to a specific directory,
but it need to be started on the first free directory.

Comment: @jny How can I force the ThreadPool to execute the next task, only on a free directory?

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 options...

1. If the directory name more or less does not matter, use the threadname within the task to specify the directory and configure threadpool with the `maximum number of threads <= number of directories`, e.g

   ```
    @Override
    @Bean
   public Executor getAsyncExecutor() {
   ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
   executor.setMaxPoolSize(numberofdirectories);
   executor.setCorePoolSize(corepoolsize);
   executor.setThreadNamePrefix("directorynameprefix");

   return executor;
   ```

   }
2. Use Java Concurrent collection like [ConcurrentLinkedDeque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedDeque.html) to keep track of free directories and access it from the task itself. There would need to be a logic for cases when directory is not available